# Problemas para validar un mail y contraseña con php

Tags: php, sql

Tengo un formulario el cual tiene dos campos, uno para el email y otro para la contraseña. Lo que quiero es mirar si existe ese email con esa contraseña en la base de datos y si es así entrar en mi cuenta.

El problema es que aunque el email y la contraseña existan en la base de datos, el array que recorro para coger lo valores de la base de datos parece no haber nada.

He aqui el codigo php :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['posta']) && !empty($_POST['posta'])){
        $local = 0;
        if($local == 0){
            $server ="localhost";
            $user = "root";
            $pass = "";
            $db = "quiz";
        }else{
            $server ="localhost";
            $user = "id3001514_t17";
            $pass = "12345";
            $db = "id3001514_quiz";
        }
        $konektatu = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die("Ezin izan da konektatu ");
        mysqli_select_db($konektatu,$db) or die("Ezin izan da konektatu datu basera ");

        if(isset($_POST['pasahitza']) && !empty($_POST['pasahitza'])){
            $sql1 = "SELECT Posta,Pasahitza FROM erabiltzailea WHERE Posta = '$_POST[posta]' AND Pasahitza = '$_POST[pasahitza]'";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($konektatu, $sql1); 
            if ($result1) { 
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) { 
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
                        if (isset($row[0])){
                            echo"$row[0]['Posta']";                //EMPIEZA A FALLAR AQUI Y SALE ESTE ERROR : Notice: Undefined offset: 0
                            echo"$row[0]['Pasahitza']";
                            if ($row[0]['Posta'] == $_POST['posta'] && $row[0]['Pasahitza'] == $_POST['pasahitza']) { 
                                echo"Posta eta pasahitza zuzenak"; 
                                header("Location: layoutLogeatuta.html"); 
                            } else { 
                                echo"Posta edo pasahitza okerrak dira." . mysqli_error($konektatu); 
                            } 
                        }   
                    } 
                } 
            }
            mysqli_close($konektatu);
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Eso te pasa por que mysqli_query() te devuelve un objeto lo que quiere decir que para comparar debes recorrer ese objeto, intenta usando en el if lo siguiente: mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)['Posta'] y lo mismo con $result2a ver si te funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que

`Posta => Correo Electronico`

y

`Pasahitza => Contraseña`

y centrandonos en tu query, tu hubieras podido obtener el mismo resultado en un solo query por ejemplo:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT Posta, Pasahitza   
FROM erabiltzailea 
WHERE Posta = '$_POST[posta]' 
and Pasahitza =  '$_POST[pasahitza]'";
```

> Recuerda siempre que uno de los peligros mas grandes en cuanto a seguridad es pasar los input de los usuarios directos a un query. Lo mejor es usar los [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Sería bueno leyeras sobre este tema. Un link como referencia [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php?rq=1)

Entonces suponiendo que solo sea posible una sola fila como resultado la comparación sería algo como:

```
 $result1 = mysqli_query($konektatu,$sql1);

 if($result1['Posta'] == $_POST['posta'] && $result1['Pasahitza'] == $_POST['pasahitza']){
    echo"Posta eta pasahitza zuzenak";
    header("Location: layoutLogeatuta.html");   
}else{
    echo"Posta edo pasahitza okerrak dira.".mysqli_error($konektatu);    
//SIEMPRE SE METE AQUI SEAN CUAL SEAN LOS DATOS
}
```

Si el query devuelve mas de una fila entonces tendrias que recorrer el objeto como te indican @CamiloVasquez en los comentarios: `mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

Comment: @UnaiLopez puedes imprimir los valores de la base dato, para que veas como estan llegando con un echo???

Comment: @UnaiLopez puedes poner el ejemplo de como lo estas recorriendo??

Comment: He hecho lo siguiente y sigue fallando:

$result1 = mysqli_query($konektatu,$sql1);
    if($result1!=NULL){
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)>0){
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
       if($row['Posta'] == '$_POST[posta]' && $row['Pasahitza'] == '$_POST[pasahitza]'){
        echo"Posta eta pasahitza zuzenak";
        header("Location: layoutLogeatuta.html");   
       }else{
        echo"Posta edo pasahitza okerrak dira.".mysqli_error($konektatu);    
       }
       }
     }
    }

Comment: @UnaiLopez prueba este: `$result1 = mysqli_query($konektatu, $sql1);
if ($result1) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            if ($row[0]['Posta'] == $_POST['posta'] && $row[0]['Pasahitza'] == $_POST['pasahitza']) {
                echo"Posta eta pasahitza zuzenak";
                header("Location: layoutLogeatuta.html");
            } else {
                echo"Posta edo pasahitza okerrak dira." . mysqli_error($konektatu);
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Me aparece este error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\lab3\logIn.php on line 88
Posta edo pasahitza okerrak dira.

la linea 88 es esta : 

if ($row[0]['Posta'] == $_POST['posta'] && $row[0]['Pasahitza'] == $_POST['pasahitza']) {